# Swift - Get list of countries -> fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, fatal-error, countries

I asked few days ago about how to get a list of countries in Swift, and you solved the first part of it (here: [Swift - Get list of countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315741/swift-get-list-of-countries)), but I am not able to get the final countries list because it gives an error:

```
var countries: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
countries = NSMutableArray(capacity: (NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes().count))
for countryCode : AnyObject in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
  let dictionary : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object:countryCode, forKey:NSLocaleCountryCode)
  let identifier : NSString     = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(dictionary)
  // next line - fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
  let country    : NSString     = 
    NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: identifier)
  countries.addObject(country)
}
println(countries)
```

What does the "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None" error mean? I've been trying and searching about it but I haven't find the solution yet :/

Million thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't unwrap 'Optional.None'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006287/cant-unwrap-optional-none)

Comment: its basically a nullpointer

Answer (score 2):

this line is an Optional String

```
  let identifier : NSString = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(dictionary)
```

replace with

```
  let identifier : NSString? = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(dictionary)
```

and then

```
if identifier {
  let country : NSString = 
     NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: identifier!)   
 countries.addObject(country)
}
```

Comment: sorry it should be ? not !.

Comment: and identifier should be unwraped by identifier!

Answer (score 0):

Try to this one :D

```
var countries : String[] = Array()
for countryCodes : AnyObject in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
        let dictionary : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object:countryCodes, forKey:NSLocaleCountryCode)
        let identifier : NSString? = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(dictionary)
        if identifier {
            let country : NSString = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: identifier!)
            countries.append(country)
        }
    }
println(countries)
```

i think this one code can help you get a list of countries :D

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem with you, here is my code

```
for countryCodes : AnyObject in NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes() {
    let dictionary : Dictionary = [NSLocaleCountryCode: countryCodes]
    let identifier : String? = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents(dictionary)
    if let id = identifier {
        let country : String = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB").displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id)
        countries.append(country)
    }
}
```

or change from `NSLocale.currentLocale()` to `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")`

Answer (score 0):

For swift3

```
let identifier = Locale.identifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue:countryCode])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

(edited) using Locale, instead of NSLocale

```
func getCountriesList()->[String]{
    var countries = [String]()
    for code in Locale.isoRegionCodes {
        let id = Locale.identifier(fromComponents: [NSLocale.Key.countryCode.rawValue: code])
        if let name = Locale(identifier: id).localizedString(forRegionCode: code) {
            countries.append(name)
        }
    }
    return countries
}
```

Comment: Don't use `NSLocale` in Swift, use native `Locale`. Then you can omit the entire `let id = ` line and replace the next line with `let name = Locale(identifier: "en").localizedString(forRegionCode: code) ?? "Country not found for code: \(code)"`. Further in `Locale` `isoCountryCodes` is `isoRegionCodes` and the bridge cast `as String` is redundant.